# New battery drains fast

Tags: battery

I bought a new battery for my Windows Phone, but two months later  the new battery can only support my phone about 2 hours. Do you have some way to extend the usage time?

Comment: Was it a genuine battery? Where did you get it from?

Comment: Also, do you tend to wait for your battery to get low before recharging, or do you *tend* to keep it fully charged?

Answer (score 1):

If its a genuine battery, I can recommend you to go back to dealer and get it replaced under warranty. If its not, I don't think you can do much apart from running the phone on Battery Saver mode (Always).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link and follow them if your battery is working fine now! http://www.wpcentral.com/17-tips-extend-battery-life-windows-phone

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you should get your battery checked for genuine. If everything's ok, you can follow steps to last your battery for longer.

Turn off Hey Cortana.
Turn off Data when not in use.
Set your screen brightness to low.
Turning battery saver on.
Turning off Location and WiFi.

Source: [How to improve battery life in Windows Phone 10](http://www.windowsphonesearch.com/2016/01/how-to-improve-battery-life-in-Windows-Phone-10.html)